# How to create activity for automatic contribution receipts sent

Tags: receipts

Is it possible to have CiviCRM create an activity (preferably email) every time a contribution receipt is sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a Scheduled Reminder that send an email based on the contribution activity.